# How to select documents not contained in given array?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to select only those documents from the collection, which `id`s are not contained in a given array. Is it possible with **Google Firestore**? [The official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) say only about basic queries like >, <, ==

Basically I need `Parse`'s `query.whereKey("playerName", notContainedIn: names)` functionality

Answer (score 1):

No, right now this is not possible.  Firestore does not allow `!=` queries, only equality and ranges (as you mentioned with your link to the docs).

Comment: Well, that's quite annoying. Do you know if Firebase allows such queries?